# Fetching data from firestore collection in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have three different collections of database in firestore and i want to fetch the data from all these collections into my admin panel table. From the students collections i have to get the details of the students and from other two collections feedback and the details, i have to get feedback and extra informations from the details collections. At the first i am fetching my students collection data, and inside my admin table i have to fetch feedback and the extra informations details in the table along the students details.
The problem is i am getting undefined document, and in the console i am getting No doc found! message.

```
My code looks like this.

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import AdminNavbar from '../../layout/AdminNavbar';
import firebase from '../../../config/fbConfig';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [tableData, settableData] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    course: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    createdAt:""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getdata();
  }, []);

  async function getdata() {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("students").doc();
    ref.get().then((doc) => {
      const feedbackdata = doc.data();
      console.log(feedbackdata);
      if (doc.exists) {
        settableData({
          id: feedbackdata.id,
          name: feedbackdata.name,
          course: feedbackdata.course,
          email: feedbackdata.email,
          phone: feedbackdata.phone,
          createdAt: feedbackdata.createdAt
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No doc found!");
      }
    });
  }

  const tableCol = [
    {
      title: "Student ID",
      field: "id"
    },
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Course",
      field: "course"
    },
    {
      title: "Email",
      field: "email"
    },
    {
      title: "Phone",
      field: "phone"
    },
    {
      title: "Submitted at",
      field: "createdAt"
    }
  ];
  
    return (
        <>
            <AdminNavbar />
            <div className="table-div">
                <MaterialTable
          title={"Student's Feedback"}
          data={tableData}
          columns={tableCol}
          
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#01579b",
              color: "#FFF"
            },
            exportButton: true,
            selection: false,
            search: true
          }}
          
        />
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: `.collection("students").doc()` - the `.doc()` here expects the name of the document you want to get. Your current usage seems invalid. See the [Firestore Docs - Read Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for examples

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the Firestore module here is incorrect. Make sure to take a look at the [Firestore Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for basic examples.

In your code:

```js
async function getdata() {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("students").doc(); // THIS IS INVALID
```

The `doc` method expects the name of a document to fetch - your current usage doesn't tell Firestore which document you want

```js
// You want a particular document
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("students").doc("<documentIdHere>");

// You want to get the list of documents in the student collection
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("students");
    const snapshot = await ref.get();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
```

*More complex examples and use cases can be found in the Firestore Docs and are often discussed in other StackOverflow questions.*

Comment: How can i show all the documents of the students collection in the table?

Comment: console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data()); I'm getting the data but not able print this data in my table, can you help me out?

Comment: @Wasim that's fairly basic React and JS code, I can't do the work for you. You need to update the state with the incoming data and then map the state value in the table. You can google how to guides for both and find plenty of examples