# How i get all subcollection in document in collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i looking for document talk about this my problem but it look like quite quite a few

i have one collection like this
collection(user1)=>uid=>document( collection(Product => uid ),nameUser.... bla bla)

i get all  Product's document user1 this is quite easy but how i get this with user 2, user 3 and gathered into array product of all user?

i have tried this code in below but it doesn't understand

```
getData = async () => {
    const a = [];
    await firebase.firestore().collection('user').doc().collection('Product').onSnapshot(sanpham => {

      sanpham.forEach((doc) => {
        a.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })
      })
    })
    this.setState({ data: a });
  }
```

Comment: I answered this [exact same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910919/fetching-data-from-firestore-collection-in-react-js/66911126#66911126) you can use the answer there and it'll work pretty much the same

Comment: t have read but it didn't solve my problem, I am expecting a concise non-nested query solution or collectionGroup the better

Comment: I'm querying all subcollection in a document, not all document in collection

Comment: My suggested solution is to get all the users (using how it's shown in my answer) and then from that you can get the products for each user and collect into an object or array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the documents from all `Product` collections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group).

To use it, you'd do:

```
await firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('Product').onSnapshot(sanpham => {
  sanpham.forEach((doc) => {
    a.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })
  })
})
```

If you want to know which `user` a product belongs to, you can determine that with:

```
const productRef = doc.ref;
const productCollectionRef = productRef.parent;
const userRef = productCollectionRef.parent;
console.log(userRef.id);
```

Comment: oh collection don't need query 'Where'??? i think collectionGroup and Where always together

Comment: Your code below I have tried but is it very similar to the other times I have tried it and I don't know how to use it?

Comment: i added it on my question it seems very cumbersome and i can't use it especially ProdiverData

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is you're having now, and how it relates to the original problem which I understood to be about loading documents from all subcollections at once. I think I addressed that above, so if you have a new problem after that, I recommend posting that as a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).